# how to avoid/shorten the SourcePath too Long files/folders name

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

[image]

Please can you let me know how to (dont want to delete or avoid)shorten the **LongSourcePath files/folder**s name in **robocopy** while copying to the destination folder. As I am using this snippet:

```
robocopy %source% %destination% /MIR /E /PURGE /XF ntuser.* ntuser.dat.*
```

Any assistance or inputs here:

Comment: Can you give some more info please? If you don't show any other info on `%source%`, it will be hard to give you any other advice than rename the directories on the source path or the filenames.

Comment: try using [8.3 format](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/num/8-3-format.htm)

Comment: `subst Z: "%source%"` and then `robocopy Z:\ ...` might help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't. You can "delete" the file with robocopy by /mir'ing an empty directory as the source and the offending folder as the destination, but that will delete everything in the destination folder (bad if you don't first copy/move out what you can).

You can backup everything you can "move" that doesn't have a path name that is too long, then use the /mir trick above to delete those files.

Or, you can also do this: https://superuser.com/a/638162/1838110 which may be a better solution for you.